# Change the size and color of the box that contains the legend and the layers

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, geoportal

I am new to JavaScript. I have a code for a globe of the planet. I have to change size and colors of the box where the legend is. How can I change the size and color of the box that contains the legend and the layers? I leave the following code, where I add the visualization of the box where is the legend and the layer.

```
scene.add(greenboxes);

  var listaCapas = new LayerList({
    view:view
  });
  view.ui.add(listaCapas,"top-right");

  var homebtn = new Home({
    view:view
  });
  view.ui.add(homebtn, "top-left");

  var leyend = new Legend({
    view:view
  });
  view.ui.add(leyend, "bottom-right");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are dictated by the ESRI ArcGIS API for Javascript but you can adjust the ESRI defaults by referencing the specific DOM element & adjusting the CSS. The following placed in a linked style.css file worked for me using version 4.25 of the API. Or alternatively, it could go in the style section of your index.html.

```
/* width & color of legend */
div.esri-component.esri-legend.esri-widget.esri-widget--panel {
  max-width: 175px;
  background-color: rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.75);
}
```

There is also the option to assign an id property when the legend is created. I expected to be able to then reference that id in CSS rather than the list of class names above. However, that route did not work for me.